# BroadcastReceiver: goAsync() vs AsyncTask in onReceive()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` (or, more specifically, an `AppWidgetProvider`) in which I need to do some network operations in the `onReceive()` method... not particularly long-running (should finish within 10s, and if not then I'm happy(*) to time them out).

At present I'm executing an [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) from `onReceive()` so that the network operations don't block the UI thread, but I see that a `BroadcastReceiver` also provides a [`goAsync()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#goAsync()) method for apparently much the same purpose.

I'm struggling to find an explanation as to what exactly the differences are between using `AsyncTask` and `goAsync()` in this context... when would you use one, and when the other?

(*) I mentioned that my network operations and subsequent processing would typically finish within the 10s (**) that I understand you have before the `BroadcastReceiver` is killed (after returning from `onReceive()`).  However, ideally it would be good to allow the operations to continue beyond the 10s in particularly challenging conditions (unreliable network, slow device).  Is either of the above methods any better than the other in this respect?  At least for `goAsync()`, the docs suggest that you should still wrap things up within the 10s.  But for `AsyncTask` is it ever possible to spawn the `AsyncTask` and have the `doInBackground()` method run beyond the 10s... will it have an existence beyond the lifetime of the `BroadcastReceiver` if it is declared as a static inner class of the `BroadcastReceiver`?

(**) EDIT: the 10 second thing is in the docs for [`BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive())... specifically:

> When it runs on the main thread you should never perform long-running operations in it (there is a timeout of 10 seconds that the system allows before considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be killed).

Comment: where does it say that a receiver is 'killed' after 10 seconds?

Comment: I've added a reference in my post

Answer (score 2):

AsyncTask in receiver is a bad practice, try to avoid it because the system can kill your process and `onReceive` no guarantee its return.

`goAsync()` returns a `PendingResult` object,
the system considers the receiver as alive **until you call the `PendingResult.finish()`** on it.

Comment: So, with `goAsync()` you could keep the receiver alive for longer than the 10s... basically as long as you require to finish the operation?  Sure, there may still be an "expectation" that it should finish within 10s, but you can have longer if you need?  And about `AsyncTask`... I had thought that if it was declared as a static inner class then it has a life that is independent of the parent (receiver), and hence shouldn't be killed when the parent is?  Maybe I need to find a good tutorial on this subject...

Comment: @drmrbrewer good points. I am trying to learn the same thing. Did you get to any conclusions?

Comment: @PrimožKralj as far as I recall I stuck with `AsyncTask` but first started a `Service` and then initiated the `AsyncTask` from there

Answer (score 1):

goAsync:

if you call goAsync before the BroadcastReceiver::onReceive return, when a new broadcast comes after a while, android system will call the same receiver, just the same receiver instance where you call goAsync

AsyncTask:

if you call AsyncTask before the BroadcastReceiver::onReceive return, when a new broadcast comes after a while, the android system may call a new receiver even though the process is still running,  you may not suppose the receiver is the same as the previous one where you call AsyncTask